# Guideline to Create Master Pages for Existing Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, master-pages

I've never messed with Master Pages, and I'd like to migrate some of my existing sites over so that I can stop trying to maintain all of the duplicate coding for headers, menus, etc.

I've started with this intro: [ASP.NET 2.0 Master Pages](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp) - it is pretty good, but doesn't answer my detailed information.

Can I (and how would I if I can)

- Master Page the `<head><title>` tag? (just in case I forget to give a document a title)
- Master Page the `META` tags? After all, most of the information is redundant.
- ...and can I add extra to the `META` tag, or is it an "all or nothing" kind of thing? (like overriding ToString() and returning `base.ToString() + " my own flavor."`.
- Master Page the `CSS Stylesheet` page(s) and `JavaScript` source code?

If it helps, I code using `Notepad.exe` in Windows 7 because I do not like how most tools (especially *Microsoft*'s tools) try to "auto format" my text for me.

Maybe these topics are all basics, but I do not readily see them being answered in the tutorials I'm finding online or the information here.

Could someone point me to a good reference on how to do different things in **Master Pages**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of those things with master pages. Just put them in your .master file, similar to this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="YourPage.Master.cs" Inherits="MasterPages.YourMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Your Title</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/YourStyles.css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="bodyContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And FYI: you can turn off auto-formatting in Visual Studio if it bothers you. Using Visual Studio, while not perfect, will help you avoid simple spelling mistakes (via Intellisense) and generally speed up your development, if you learn how to use it. I would recommend using at least some kind of IDE. If not Visual Studio, then maybe MonoDevelop.

Comment: +1 - So, could I put `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="metaDescription" runat="server"><meta name="Keywords" content="jp2code" /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`? If so, I presume to replace it, I simply recall the control in my derived page and over ride the content. Is this correct?

Comment: In your content page, you would have an `<asp:Content>` tag for each of your placeholders, and whatever you put in between would be placed in that placeholder's location in the rendered page.